# Plugin for on-the-fly # => evaluation

Tags: ide, filetype-ruby

How can I evaluate Ruby code on-the-fly when you are writing it?

This is what it looks like:

```
5 + 5 # => 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [IRuby](https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby) kernel for [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) / [IPython](http://ipython.org/) and [ipython-vimception](https://github.com/ivanov/ipython-vimception).  If you must do it in Vim itself you might try the [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython) plugin, but in my experience this part doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to evaluate a single line you can do this with a macro simply :

```
qq$hy:r! ruby -e '<C-r>"'<CR>
```

Decomposing :

```
qq                " record a new macro
v$hy              " select the current line minus the ^m
:r!               " prepare to read a command
ruby -e '<C-r>"'  " call ruby inline mode executing
<CR>              " execute the whole thing
```

You now have the result on the new line, feel free to customize :)

Comment: The problem is, it has to evaluate the whole file. And replace `# =>` on every line.

Comment: that is right, but for quick evaluation of a single line (as I first understand the question) this should work, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@tomstuart](https://twitter.com/tomstuart/status/618356806025388032):

I use https://github.com/t9md/vim-ruby-xmpfilter with xmpfilter.